Warning: React instrumentation encountered an error: Error: The children should not have changed if we pass in the same set - nextjs
I get this error message in console while switiching from one page to another.
I dont think I am using the same component in both pages
I think it is a new error which might come with react19 but I am not sure
Any suggestion?

This warning is React-related and usually occurs when components are passed to a React context or provider, and React detects changes to children in the context when they remain the same objects.
To avoid this problem, make sure you don't modify context or provider objects directly, as React expects objects to remain unchanged if their references haven't changed.
If you are using a React Context or Provider, make sure that the values you provide remain unchanged or, if they change, create new objects or values to avoid this error.
